# Javascript .onclick = functionName passing parameters

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this code:

```
var bt = document.getElementById("bt");
bt.onclick = randomFunc;
```

Now, how can I pass some parameters to `randomFunc`?

Answer (score 4):

Create a new function which calls `randomFunc` and specify the parameters there.

```
bt.onclick = function () {
    randomFunc(foo, bar, baz);
};
```

Or, if you can limit support to browsers which support `bind`, use that method to create your function:

```
bt.onclick = randomFunc.bind(this, foo, bar, baz);
```

Comment: While I'd recommend `addEventListener()` over `onclick =`, it doesn't have any features to help with the problem of binding arguments.

Comment: @Quentin indeed - I just couldn't leave the OP's use of obsolete DOM0 event handling go unchallenged... ;-)