# Javascript - Function to use onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I want to create a function and then use with `onclick` method, for example:

```
one = document.getElementById("oneID");
```

then instead of writing function for each `onclick():`

```
one.onclick = function(x) {
     tempStack.push(parseFloat(one.value));
     viewTemp.value += one.value;
}
```

I want to use a single function:

```
one.click = input(one);
```

but I'm not sure how to do it in the correct way for example the below I tried, doesn't work:

```
var input = function(x) {
        tempStack.push(parseFloat(x.value));
        viewTemp.value += x.value;
}
```

Lastly, no external JavaScript libraries to aid this question, vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript .onclick = functionName passing parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546480/javascript-onclick-functionname-passing-parameters)

Comment: Isn't better to call your single method on each HTML element's onClick event?

Comment: @user3102101 accept an answer if it suits your needs. There is a tick mark on the left of each one.

Comment: @user3102101 But you can accept answers with any rep =)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to pass a function as a reference, not call it:

```
one.onclick = input;
```

In this case you won't be able to pass an argument, but you can use `this` as a reference for the DOM element on which event is fired:

```
function input() {
    tempStack.push(parseFloat(this.value));
    viewTemp.value += this.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method with using JavaScript's [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), as a previous answer mentioned, using `this` to pass through the DOM Node Element to use within the `inputFunction`.

```
<input type="text" value="64.23" id="bt" />

<script>
     function inputFunction( x ) {
         console.log( x.value ); //Console Logs 64.23
     }

     var bt = document.getElementById("bt");
     bt.addEventListener( 'click', function(){ inputFunction( this )}, false );
</script>
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhq6t/

Answer (score 0):

Think about functions as a normal objects, so the way is:

```
function input (event) {
   // Process the event...

   // event is my event object
   // this is the object which trigger the event
   // event.target is my button
}

on.onclick = input;
```

You must assign the `input` function as a normal variable.

The function `input` will receive an event object as parameter. Also you can refer to the button clicked with `this`.

Maybe the [mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/click)   or [the real w3c site](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript) would explain it better.

Comment: W3Schools is an awful, frequently wrong, frequently out of date tutorial / reference site and is not associated with the W3C at all.

Comment: I'll take that, thanks ^^. Maybe you could recommend us another reference site?

Comment: In the general case, `this` isn't actually the object clicked. It is the object on which the event fired. `event.target` is the object clicked. (They can be different since elements (although not `<input>` which *presumably* `input` is) can have descendants).

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be achieved by following:

Add this method in your script tag:

```
function input(x) {
    /*tempStack.push(parseFloat(x.value));
    viewTemp.value += x.value;*/

    alert(x.id);       
}
```

And then call this method onClick event of your buttons / anchors like:

```
<input type="button" id="oneID" value="oneID" onClick="input(this);"/>
<input type="button" id="twoID" value="twoID" onClick="input(this);"/>
<a href="#" id="threeID" onClick="input(this);">threeID</a>
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Avd5U/1/

Comment: You were adding onClick event through javascript, add them directly in your tags.

Answer (score -2):

ok, so just create a function with a parameter in it like:

```
function setValue(input){
    tempStack.push(parseFloat(input.value));
    viewTemp.value += input.value;
}
```

and then call the function on the click of that element like:

```
var one = document.getElementById("oneID");
one.click = setValue(one);
```

Good luck!

Comment: What have you changed except for renaming function?